# How do I catch xlink:href errors in D3?

Tags: d3.js, error-handling

```
transition.select("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      //fix icon error if icon does not exist in folder
      return 'assets/64pxBlue/file.png';
      // return d.icon
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {return d.position_x ? d.position_x : '0px'})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return d.position_y ? d.position_y : '-10px'})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return d.value ? d.value : '20px'})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return d.value ? d.value : '20px'})
}
```

I'm trying to visualize files in the form of PNGs.  After parsing the string; it will match the string with the according png and render.  However, I don't have all possible png so I need to return a default png if it doesn't exist in my assets/64pxBlue/ directory.

In my devtools, there's a GET error.  How do I catch that error, and return file.png if there's an error?

Answer (score 0):

D3 does not have anything to support this but you can do it with simple js like below:

```js
d3.selectAll("img")[0].forEach(function(i, n){
  i.onload=imageFound;//on error call this function
  i.onerror=imageNotFound;//on success call this function
  if (n ==0)
  i.src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg";
  else
    i.src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/blah-blah.jpg";//set a wrong url
})


function imageFound() {
    console.log('That image is found and loaded');
}

function imageNotFound(me) {
    //set default url in case image not found
    me.target.src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif";
    console.log("defaut image")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<img  alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

<img alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```